# How to add specific Class in CSS

Tags: css, file

if I add a css class to my div, it will be overwritten with v-slot-tradeMatrixLayout. How can I specify this class specifically in my CSS file so that only this is called. The tradeMatrixLayout is given to a VerticalLayout.

This will be examined in chrome

```
<div class="v-slot v-slot-tradeMatrixLayout">
```

And this is my CSS file

```
.tradeMatrixLayout{
 margin-left: 15px !important;
}
```

How can the div call my specifically written class?

Comment: you mean you want to add css class to this div? add this class 'tradeMatrixLayout' in html class attribute like - `<div class="v-slot v-slot-gewerkeMatrixLayout tradeMatrixLayout">` thats it

Comment: or use in css `.v-slot .v-slot-tradeMatrixLayout .tradeMatrixLayout{...}`

Comment: I did it, but it was overwritten with v-slot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class attribute can receive multiple CSS classes by using their name and separated by a space, as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). For your case you can add it like:

```
<div class="v-slot tradeMatrixLayout">
```

In this example, you are adding 2 classes: `v-slot` and `tradeMatrixLayout`.

if `v-slot` is overwritting whatever you are trying to set with `tradeMatrixLayout`, then it means that you have to play with [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). In summary, some rules have more importance than others, even if you use `!important` (imagine you have 3 classes that use `!important`, which one should be used?). The higher the specificity, the more important is the rule.

> The following list of selector types increases by specificity:
>
> - Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., ::before).
> - Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g.,
>     [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
> - ID selectors (e.g., > #example).

if you want it to have more specificity, either change your CSS to:

```
div.tradeMatrixLayout{
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

of add it using an id:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="v-slot tradeMatrixLayout">

div#myDiv.tradeMatrixLayout{
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: @sulox32 glad I could help, don't forget to have a proper read on the links I added, so that you can understand Specificity a bit further and apply it when creating and using CSS files and classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use javascript to add the class by manipulating the DOM.

```
function myFunction() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("v-slot");
    el.classList.add("tradeMatrixLayout");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be end with your class

```
[class$='tradeMatrixLayout']{
  color: red;
  margin-left: 15px !important;
}
```

Just try above code it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

The .class selector selects elements with a specific class attribute.
To select elements with a specific class, write a period (.) character, followed by the name of the class.
You can also specify that only specific HTML elements should be affected by a class. To do this, start with the element name, then write the period (.) character, followed by the name of the class

I don't fully understand what you clearly want though? What you have seems okay?

```
v-slot v-slot-gewerkeMatrixLayout
```

This is referencing to these 2 classes, It cannot use the same elements from both as it will be overwritten. But if you have 2 different instructions it should work

Answer (score 0):

You could just specify the class your in your CSS like this

```
.v-slot-tradeMatrixLayout {
    margin-left: 15px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another CSS with that CSS class (v-slot)
Like:

```
.v-slot{
     margin-right:5px;
}
.v-slot.tradeMatrixLayout{
    margin-left:50px
}
```

And your html will look like

```
<div class="v-slot"></div>
<div class="v-slot tradeMatrixLayout"></div>
```

```css
.v-slot{
        border: 3px solid blue;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin-left: 5px;
}
.v-slot.tradeMatrixLayout{
        margin-left:50px
}
```

```html
<div class="v-slot"></div>
<div class="v-slot tradeMatrixLayout"></div>
```